# Keep one week and one week after data if two dates are same

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I have a dataset looks like this:

[image]

I want to keep the data one week before and one week after if "Date" equals "Fdate." For example, in the given data sample, 1/16/2011 is same in both columns for 1031, then I want to keep the data from 1/9/2011 to 1/23/2011 (based on Date).
How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to datetime, add ± 1W and select with [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
df[['Date', 'Fdate']] = df[['Date', 'Fdate']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

delta = pd.DateOffset(days=7)
# or
# delta = pd.to_timedelta('7D')

df.loc[df['Date'].between(df['Fdate'].sub(delta), df['Fdate'].add(delta))]
```

Output:

```
    Gvkey       Date      Fdate prec
4    1031 2011-01-09 2011-01-16  5,2
5    1031 2011-01-10 2011-01-16  5,3
6    1031 2011-01-11 2011-01-16  5,4
7    1031 2011-01-12 2011-01-16  5,5
8    1031 2011-01-13 2011-01-16  5,6
9    1031 2011-01-14 2011-01-16  5,7
10   1031 2011-01-15 2011-01-16  5,8
11   1031 2011-01-16 2011-01-16  5,9
```

Comment: Thank you, that works well for seven days before. However, as you can see, because the Fdate will change in the following financial year, this coding does not work for seven days later. Does there have any good solution to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to ignore the year? In this case retrieve the year from "Date" and replace that of "FDate" with it for the comparison.

Comment: Sorry for the inarticulation. I mean, based on your coding, I can only get seven days before the date, but it does not offer the seven-day later result. I wonder why this happens